# Create 2D array from 1D array using loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I want to create a 2D array with three 1D arrays. Each NUM in the function variables is the length of each 1D array.
The result should be `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

But all I get is `,,3,,,6,,,9`. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function infiniteLoop(arr, num) {
  var answer = [];
  var count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < num[i]; j++, count++) {
      answer[i] = [];
      answer[i][j] = arr[count];
    }

  }
  return answer;
}

document.write(infiniteLoop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 3, 3]));
```

Comment: Please don't edit suggestions into your question, because that invalidates answers to the previous version of your question. Regarding your edit, you have added the `answer[i] = [];` part in the wrong place. Have another look at my answer, or Thomas's (but don't use `new Array()`).

Comment: Sorry for the edit. Tried to help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional arrays per se, what it has is arrays of arrays.

When you try to use `answer[i][j]` the `answer[i]` part of that is `undefined` because you haven't set it to anything yet - at that point `answer` is just an empty array. You need to set `answer[i] = [];` to set the first element of `answer` to be an empty array, and *then* you can use `answer[i][j]`.

That will fit in your existing loop like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    answer[i] = [];    // <--- add this
    for (let j = 0; j < num[i]; j++, count++) {
      answer[i][j] = arr[count];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without testing it I believe you need to set answer[i] = [] before you loop your next array

Answer (score 1):

`answer[i]` hasn't been created. You are trying to assign a value to something that doesn't exist. You need to create `answer[i]` like this:

```
answer[i] = new Array(num[i]);
```

So, the full code:

```
function infiniteLoop(arr, num) {
  var answer = [];
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    answer[i] = new Array(num[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < num[i]; j++, count++) {
      answer[i][j] = arr[count];
    }
  }
  return answer;
}

document.write(infiniteLoop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 3, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `answer[i]` is undefined. The solution would be to add the following statement to the beginning of the first for loop:

```
answer[i] = [];
```

This should initialize `answer[i]` as an array, thus allowing you to set individual indices for it.